# WooCommerce - Product Variation - Custom Crop Size

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to customise WooCommerce crop sizes and I am currently using the following code to customise the product gallery image sizes:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', function( $size ) {
    return 'product-gallery';
} );
```

This works on the main gallery images but isn't applying to any images used in the product variations.

I have looked at documentation but cannot find a filter to target the product variation images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the same situation, the snippet you need is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_single', 'ci_theme_override_woocommerce_image_size_single' );

function ci_theme_override_woocommerce_image_size_single( $size ) {
    // Single product image: square
    return array(
        'width'  => 750,
        'height' => 750,
        'crop'   => 1,
    );
}
```